# Displaying Layer values using Graphs or Histograms in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld, ysld

I have a WMS polygon layer read from PostgreSQL, this polygon layer has different values that I would like to display using bar graphs per polygon. The polygons are 4, the bar should ideally look like below (QGIS histogram, but for the purpose of this question, I have only given a few values). The values for the layers are as in the below table.

[image]

[image]

Here is the SLD (following this tutorial https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/pretty_maps/charting.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <NamedLayer>
    <Name></Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Pie charts</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke />
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </Geometry>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
                  xlink:href="http://chart?cht=bvg&amp;chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&amp;chd=t:${Loss_of_Well_Control;Production_Well_Equipment_FailureProduction_Well_Operational_Discharge;}"/>
                <Format>application/chart</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Add>
                  <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Mul>
                    <ogc:Div>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>20000000.0</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Div>
                    <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Mul>
                </ogc:Add>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The above SLD returns the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid cql expression &apos;Loss_of_Well_Control;Production_Well_Equipment_Failure;
Invalid cql expression &apos;Loss_of_Well_Control;Production_Well_Equipment_Failure;
Encountered &quot;;&quot; at line 1, column 21.
Was expecting one of:
    &lt;EOF&gt; 
    &quot;.&quot; ...
    &quot;/&quot; ...
    &quot;:&quot; ...
    &quot;*&quot; ...
    &quot;+&quot; ...
    &quot;-&quot; ...
    &lt;IDENTIFIER&gt; ...
    &quot;(&quot; ...
     Parsing : Loss_of_Well_Control;Production_Well_Equipment_Failure;Loading_Unloading_Failure;Equipment_Failure.
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

The error message suggests an issue with the semicolons however changing this does not solve the problem. Any idea of where I am going wrong.

[image]

When loading the SLD, it looks like this and returns the service exception error, complaining about the layer name.
[image]

Comment: I think each variable should be seperate `chd=t:${Loss_of_Well_Control};${Production_Well_Equipment_Failure};${Production_Well_Operational_Discharge;}`

Comment: @IanTurton that's right, I have updated the Question to add a snapshot of how the SLD looks like, it shows two blocks or squares. However, I am still getting a service exception error. I have replaced "PERSONS" with my LayerName but still fails. The exception error says the requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of "LayerName" and the layer is: "GeoServer Store Name and LayerName".